# AAVE grammar: Difference between "continue to/keep on" vs "steady"

Tags: tenses, african-american-vernacular-english, aspect

For those who are speakers of AAVE or those who are relatively learned in this area, could someone explain to me the context in which one would use "steady" as an aspectual marker, and its difference with "keep on/continue" (beside, of course, certain obvious impossible constructions such as "to steady" compared to "to continue"). I think that I may have an understanding but not fully.

Example (in AAVE):

> I see a man over there steady working.

which might be in standard English

> I see a man over there, continuing to work.
>
> I see a man over there who keeps on working.

P.S.: By the way, I am an African-American who is not a personal speaker of AAVE, though I live with parents who are and live amongst peers who do speak it. Thus, I do generally understand it and I have been recently studying it.

Comment: I think you need to give some examples.

Comment: Sorry, but there is absolutely nothing that identifies that sentence as being AAVE. It could be regional, too. How can you live with parents who speak AAVE and peers who speak and not speak it? Sounds crazy to me.

Comment: @Lambie: *steady working* is presumably what identifies that sentence as being AAVE. It's not something I (and most native English speakers) would say. And it's discussed in [books on AAVE](https://books.google.com/books?id=bcpuNbPu-LgC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22steady+working%22&source=bl&ots=woO1DaUrgX&sig=ACfU3U3t9CL5ZsQ4ZbhNXXo72jV_QxbUGQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_yoyG_szgAhWEc98KHdOVCWo4ChDoATAIegQIABAB#v=onepage&q=%22steady%20working%22&f=false), e.g. *People be on them jobs for thirty years just steady working*.

Comment: @PeterShor That is the claim, yes. And I am saying it could be southern, Appalachian, working class, northeast, or western rural speech and god knows what else. Nothing makes it inherently AAVE. Also, the "translation" in grey is not necessarily right. In my head I hear: "He been workin' steady". The native speaker thing is "de trop" in my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie: the question is ***not*** about whether the sentence itself is AAVE. The question is *exactly what does steady mean in AAVE*, with the example sentence *I see a man over there steady working*. Are you denying that *steady* is a verb marker in AAVE, that means something different than it does in standard English, where it is an adverb? If *steady* is used as a similar verb marker in some other English dialects, does it make any difference to the question?

Comment: Howard was recently described ****in The New York Times**** as "one of those steady-working actors who usually land big parts in small films and small parts in big ones."https://newsok.com/article/2571358/tulsa-native-jeanne-tripplehorn-stars-in-hallmarks-old-man

Comment: Dan Nusbaum has been steady working on James and Nicole Harris 04 cobra motor today . Waiting on Dave Guys custom cams and a few other components as this girl will be hitting the dyno jet soon enough. Nascar speech https://www.facebook.com/pages/category/Product-Service/DGR-Performance-1966998320251170/ I rest my case.

Comment: If you think the translation is not right, that's probably because you're translating the non-AAVE sentence *"I see a man over there steady working"* into English. The OP knows much more AAVE than either you or I do.

Comment: I am saying that I'm not buying that "steady working" is only AAVE. I also don't buy that you live with parents who are AAVE speakers and are not an AAVE speaker yourself. There is something very fishy about that statement.

Comment: This may be a very subtle distinction, but in standard English 'continuing' is a formal vocabulary item and while a good translation to the formal register for 'continuous aspect' is not particularly grammatical (whatever that means). On the other hand, 'keep' and 'stop' are almost grammatical particles (like 'have') of aspect. (I have never heard this use of 'steady' so very curious to see answers here).

Comment: @Lambie Those may be reasonable inferences ('not just AAVE', 'fishy') but are mostly irrelevant. So what if non-AAVE does it? maybe how AAVE does it is not like the others (an answer might address this). So what if the sociolinguistic situation doesn't match your expectations. It turns out that that situation is very common around the world. adults speaking dialect, kids speaking standard with some elementary listening skills in the dialect.

Comment: @everyone I apologise for the example; it may have not been the best. (I just made it up from the top of my head). I was not nor am claiming that this construction is only found in AAVE; I do understand that AAVE share may similarly with other non-black Southern dialects of English as it developed within the same environment. I simply was trying to understand its meaning within a certain context, which I happen to know from AAVE. I did not mean to offend anyone.

Comment: Let me further clarify, by difference I mean the nuance that it possessive that differs from "keep on" which I also hear AAVE speakers use. I want to know what would make one use one or the other in a given situation.

Comment: If you made it up off the top of your head, how can we possibly know?? That said:  I think in your sentence it means: working uninterruptedly or working steadily. And not continue to work or keep on working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on AAVE, but I believe there is a general tendency in AAVE to change the form VERB ADVERB to ADJECTIVE VERB.  Thus (picking an example out of thin air), "eating quickly" might morph into "quick eating".

This same transformation is seen in "normal" English as well, of course, but the frequency and context of the transformation is probably greater in AAVE, and more of the transformations tend to become idiomatic.

I would take your original line to be equivalent to:

> I see a man over there working steadily.